# Failed to install scikit-learn but it could not in python 3.10 in jupyter notebook in window 8.1

Tags: python, pip, jupyter-notebook, python-3.10

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'G:\python\python.exe' 'G:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\Zaid\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp9x904_3n'
       cwd: C:\Users\Zaid\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hkon2hc1\scikit-learn_da5359c4d7ad4dadb4a1f14623e7a4ac
  Complete output (46 lines):
  Partial import of sklearn during the build process.
  No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "G:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 363, in <module>
      main()
    File "G:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 345, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
    File "G:\python\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\in_process\_in_process.py", line 164, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      return hook(metadata_directory, config_settings)
    File "C:\Users\Zaid\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ozjc6kz_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 174, in prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel
      self.run_setup()
    File "C:\Users\Zaid\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ozjc6kz_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 267, in run_setup
      super(_BuildMetaLegacyBackend,
    File "C:\Users\Zaid\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ozjc6kz_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 158, in run_setup
      exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'), locals())
    File "setup.py", line 319, in <module>
      setup_package()
    File "setup.py", line 315, in setup_package
      setup(**metadata)
    File "C:\Users\Zaid\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ozjc6kz_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\core.py", line 135, in setup
      config = configuration()
    File "setup.py", line 201, in configuration
      config.add_subpackage("sklearn")
    File "C:\Users\Zaid\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ozjc6kz_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 1016, in add_subpackage
      config_list = self.get_subpackage(subpackage_name, subpackage_path,
    File "C:\Users\Zaid\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ozjc6kz_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 982, in get_subpackage
      config = self._get_configuration_from_setup_py(
    File "C:\Users\Zaid\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ozjc6kz_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\numpy\distutils\misc_util.py", line 924, in _get_configuration_from_setup_py
      config = setup_module.configuration(*args)
    File "sklearn\setup.py", line 85, in configuration
      cythonize_extensions(top_path, config)
    File "C:\Users\Zaid\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hkon2hc1\scikit-learn_da5359c4d7ad4dadb4a1f14623e7a4ac\sklearn\_build_utils\__init__.py", line 47, in cythonize_extensions
      basic_check_build()
    File "C:\Users\Zaid\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hkon2hc1\scikit-learn_da5359c4d7ad4dadb4a1f14623e7a4ac\sklearn\_build_utils\pre_build_helpers.py", line 113, in basic_check_build
      compile_test_program(code)
    File "C:\Users\Zaid\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hkon2hc1\scikit-learn_da5359c4d7ad4dadb4a1f14623e7a4ac\sklearn\_build_utils\pre_build_helpers.py", line 70, in compile_test_program
      ccompiler.compile(
    File "G:\python\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 323, in compile
      self.initialize()
    File "G:\python\lib\distutils\_msvccompiler.py", line 220, in initialize
      vc_env = _get_vc_env(plat_spec)
    File "C:\Users\Zaid\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ozjc6kz_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 316, in msvc14_get_vc_env
      return _msvc14_get_vc_env(plat_spec)
    File "C:\Users\Zaid\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-ozjc6kz_\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\msvc.py", line 270, in _msvc14_get_vc_env
      raise distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError(
  distutils.errors.DistutilsPlatformError: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
```

Comment: first describe problem in question body, not in title. And use special functions to format error.

Comment: `Python 3.10` is very new version. Some modules are not ready for this version. Maybe better wait few months and use `3.9` or even `3.8`

Comment: Sklearn has some code in C/C++ and it needs C/C++ compiler, and last line of your error shows you link where you can get C/C++ compiler.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+Microsoft+Visual+C%2B%2B+14.0+or+greater+is+required

Answer (score 0):

download c++ compiler from https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
I'm sure you could have read that yourself man :/